# Removing time zone from Joda DateTime object

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, jodatime

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
DateTime temp = df.withOffserParsed().parseDateTime("1970-01-02T00:00:00");
Date date = temp.toDate();
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date);
long epoch_start_date = dateTime.getMillis();
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

This prints out 1970-01-02T00:00:00.000+12:00

Is there any way to remove the Time Zone (+12:00 bit) from the dateTime object? It results in the resultant time being 2 Jan 1970 12:00pm rather than the desired 2 Jan 1970 12:00 am.

Comment: As a workaround, I tried LocalDateTime instead of DateTime. The problem with that, however, is that I am unable to call getLocalMillis() on the object to get the epoch time. "The method getLocalMillis() from the type LocalDateTime is not visible".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's the local time offset from UTC/GMT.

> Is there any way to remove the Time Zone (+12:00 bit) from the dateTime object?

Yes, there is a way, but it would result in the wrong time. Assuming you live in Fiji or Kiribati, the time given is the correct time. It's expressed with (+12:00) to indicate which time zone you're in.

> It results in the resultant time being 1 Jan 1970 12:00pm rather than the desired **1 Jan 1970 12:00 am**.

Not in actual fact, due to the reason I've given. The desired time is **2** Jan 1970, not 1 Jan. The GMT time is 1 Jan at 12:00pm at that moment, and your local time is 2 Jan at 12:00am.

Having given you proper warning, here's how you could work around the time zone:

```
DateTimeFormatter df = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
DateTime temp = df.parseDateTime("1970-01-02T00:00:00");
Date date = temp.toDate();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);
int offset = calendar.getTimeZone().getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, offset);
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(calendar);
System.out.println(dateTime);
```

Just keep in mind, by doing this you may be throwing away any benefit you were getting from Joda expressing time in UTC.

Comment: That's the Pacific/Auckland time. I do realise it would result in a 'wrong' time but I need it to be 1 Jan 1970 12:00 am rather than 12pm. Could you please elaborate on the workaround (if any)? Thanks.